How to shutdown a PC at a specified time, with option to cancel?
I have been experimenting with the crontab file and making a .sh script file, but I haven't been able to either: cancel the shutdown or reliably show a message in the terminal as a "warning" when I boot up the system.
To verify if the two lines have been executed I've used at -l and shutdown 00:00 but crontab doesn't seem to execute it "@reboot"?
I also tried executing the lines via "startup applications", but that doesn't work either - even when I use the sleep command to delay the lines separately.
I have the desktop Ubuntu 24.04 LTS installed, but I set the system to boot into multi-user-target mode by default, whereas I have to log into my user on this mode and when I switch to the GUI (alias to boot into graphical-target.) - maybe this causes the issue?

From command line ...
shutdown 17:00
shutdown +60

will shutdown (1) at 17:00 or (2) 60 minutes from now.
shutdown -c 

will cancel a pending shutdown except the ones where you use now or +0 as these are executed immediately.

but crontab doesn't seem to execute it "@reboot"? I

That would be
@reboot    root   /usr/sbin/shutdown 00:00

in /etc/crontab, Use absolute paths as a precaution (as cron by default does not add $PATH).
